# Update column from same table column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table t1.

```
 table t1

id post_id tags
1     null  a
2     1     null
3     1     null
4     null  b
```

I want to update tags where post_id = id.
I tried a query it is giving me zero output.

post_id is always null when tags exists and tags is always null when post_id exists

```
update t1 set tags = tags where post_id = id;
```

Can u guys frame it properly for me. Please help me

Comment: Its better if i won't need to create a temp table to get this

Comment: `set tags = tags` this query will not update anything even if it runs

Comment: Why would you want to update the tags with the same tags value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update t1 a join t1 b on a.id = b.post_id set b.tag = a.tag`

Comment: What different is it from the real one? updating a value with itself does not change anything

Comment: I believe OP wants to take the tag where id=1, and set the tag equal to that value where all post_id = 1, so on and so forth. I might have the a and b backwards though.

Comment: Thank You Mister Melancholy. This can help me changing other things

Comment: Any time. Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: it asked me to wait 6 min while accepting it. I don't know why it said.

Comment: Probably to make sure that the really smart guy that's potentially typing the long answer has a chance to get accepted too.

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1 set tags = tags where post_id = id;
```

Here no record will update because  `tags = tags`.You are updating the column with that column value.

Comment: PSR, Hanky. How can i get this.

Comment: Which value you want to save in tags field for this query?

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1 set tags = tags where post_id = id;
```

That means set A=A, 1=1, B=B, Set something to itself. That won't update anything. You have to provide a different value to update that, for example

```
update t1 set tags = "Testing 123" where post_id = id;
```